# I'm having trouble querying an XDocument using LINQ

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm new to LINQ so I gather I just have some of my syntax wrong. I've looked at many examples online but everyone seems to have their own style.

Here's the XML data I'm querying against:

```
<ajax-response>
    <response type="object" id="unknown">
        <generic response="Success" message="Channel status will follow" />
    </response>
    <response type="object" id="unknown">
        <generic event="Status" privilege="Call" channel="SIP/452-000006fc" calleridnum="452" calleridname="Joe" connectedlinenum="430" connectedlinename="device" accountcode="" channelstate="6" channelstatedesc="Up" context="macro-dial-one" extension="s" priority="37" seconds="54" bridgedchannel="SIP/430-000006fd" bridgeduniqueid="1363822334.1829" uniqueid="1363822334.1828" />
    </response>
    <response type="object" id="unknown">
        <generic event="Status" privilege="Call" channel="SIP/430-000006fd" calleridnum="430" calleridname="device" connectedlinenum="452" connectedlinename="Joe" account="" state="Up" bridgedchannel="SIP/452-000006fc" bridgeduniqueid="1363822334.1828" uniqueid="1363822334.1829" />
    </response>
    <response type="object" id="unknown">
        <generic event="StatusComplete" items="2" />
    </response>
</ajax-response>
```

and here's what I have so far:

```
Function ParseXML(statusXML As XmlDocument) As String
    Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(New XmlNodeReader(statusXML))
    Dim parsed As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    Dim query = From generic In xdoc.Descendants("generic") _
                Where generic.Attribute("privilege") IsNot Nothing And generic.Attribute("privilege").Value = "Call" _
                Select connectedlinenum = generic.Attribute("connectedlinenum").ToString, _
                       calleridnum = generic.Attribute("calleridnum").ToString

    For Each i In query
        parsed.Append(i.connectedlinenum).Append(",").Append(i.calleridnum).Append(vbCrLf)
    Next
    Return parsed.ToString
End Function
```

I'm guessing I am misunderstanding how my `generic` object is supposed to be working, because I get a `NullReferenceException` in my Where clause when I try to reference it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Xml parsing, but in two of the nodes you do not have the `privilege` attribute. Could that be causing the error?

In that case, what happens if you change the `And` to `AndAlso` in the `Where` clause? That way it would not evaluate the latter part of the statement if there is no `privilege` attribute.

Comment: If I switch to `AndAlso` I no longer get an exception, but now I'm getting nothing, so there's still something wrong with my LINQ expression. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Hmmm, not sure why that is, sorry. Could you try `CStr(generic.Attribute("privilege").Value).Equals("Call")` for the second part maybe?

Comment: The 2nd part isn't being evaluated because of the `AndAlso`, so basically `generic.Attribute("privilege")` isn't actually doing what I'd hoped it would do. I am either declaring `generic` incorrectly, or querying against it in the wrong way.

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange, that should only happen if `privilege` attribute is nothing, so only for the first two nodes... and you should get the two other nodes back. The only other thing I could think of is that you might need `Select New With {}` to select an anonymous type. Otherwise I can't see anything wrong with the query and am out of suggestions, sorry.